# SSRS- Drill down to sub report of a bar chart on click on a particular color of the bar

Tags: reporting-services

I have a bar chart which can have many colors on each bar, Now if i click on a bar, i am getting all the data related to that particular bar. Is it possible to click only on a particular color and get related data instead of whole bar? 
To be more precise, in the below image if I click on 16/6/2013 bar, I am getting all the data related to the bar, but is it possible to click on red and green colors of the bar separately and get the relevant data? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters you are passing to the subreport.  You can pass multiple parameters.  It sounds like you are massing the date as a parameter but not the months, which drives the color in the bar chart.

In your series properties you should have at least 2 parameters shown in the list to pass to the subreport. 
[image]